# Samsung alarm volume during phone calls

Tags: samsung, alarm, samsung-one-ui

During calls, my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra has an extremely low alarm volume. This is a problem because I'm missing my alarms. I've used other third party apps such as Sleep, but to no avail. This didn't happen on my Pixel 6.